# Returning null values with all types of returning data Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying out the `StreamBuilder` so I call the API and the return values of the snapshot are always null. When I print the `print(snapshot.error.toString());` it returns `null`. I've tried parsing the data differently but failed to do so. Here is the complete code:

```
  var posts = <Post>[];
  var controller = StreamController<List<Post>>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPosts();
  }

  fetchPosts() async {
    final resp =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
    final data = json.decode(resp.body);

    posts = data.map<Post>((e) => Post()).toList();
    print(posts.isEmpty); // returns false
    pirnt(data); // returns the entire data
    controller.add(posts);
  }

  bool isSwitched = false;
  void toggleSwitch(bool value) {
    if (isSwitched == false) {
      controller.add(posts..sort((k1, k2) => k1.id.compareTo(k2.id)));
      print('Switch Button is ON');
    } else {
      controller.add(posts..sort((k1, k2) => k2.id.compareTo(k1.id)));

      print('Switch Button is OFF');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                  child: Text('sort ascending'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    toggleSwitch(isSwitched = !isSwitched);
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder<List<Post>>(
            initialData: posts,
            stream: controller.stream,
            builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print(snapshot.error.toString);
                  Post post = snapshot.data[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('${posts[index].id}'), // returns null
                    subtitle: Text('${post.id}'), // returns null
                    trailing: Text('${snapshot.data[index].id}'), // returns null
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

The Post model:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:core';

class Post extends ChangeNotifier {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  Post({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      body: json['body'],
    );
  }
}
```

Am I parsing the data wrong in the API call? Or is it something else? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `print(snapshot.error.toString);` -> `print(snapshot.error);` (or `print(snapshot.error.toString());`)

Comment: It returns `null`. I didn't realize I missed the parentheses in the print statement, I will edit the question.

Comment: so it is ok if `snapshot.error` is null, what you need is to change: `(e) => Post()` -> `(e) => Post.fromJson(e)`

Comment: I always forget that parsing `JSON` objects is different here in dart, it's not like JS. Thanks again mate, you're my lifesaver/friend these days. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my new teacher/friend @pskink that makes me learn and makes me use my brain these days, again helped me realize the mistake. Always make sure you are parsing the JSON data as it should. In my case, I forgot the `fromJson(e)` in the `fetchPosts()` method.
So the answer to this problem is:

```
posts = data.map<Post>((e) => Post.fromJson(e)).toList();
```